# Buscar por fecha en PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Buenos días, tengo la siguiente consulta que me hace una consulta por fechas a SQL SERVER:

```
            $query="SELECT art_Clave, art_Costo, kar_Fecha, kar_Cantidad, kar_Origen, alma_Existencia FROM tArticuloKardex WHERE art_Clave='".$buscar."' AND (kar_Fecha BETWEEN '".$fecha1."' AND '".$fecha2."')";
        $resultado=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
        //se desplegaran los resultados en la tabla
        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>SKU</th>";
        echo "<th>COSTO</th>";
        echo "<th>FECHA DE MOVIMIENTO</th>";
        echo "<th>PIEZAS</th>";
        echo "<th>TICKET</th>";
        echo "<th>EXISTENCIA FINAL</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['art_Clave'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['art_Costo'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['kar_Fecha'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['kar_Cantidad'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['kar_Origen'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['alma_Existencia'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';           
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

Y le paso los datos por el siguiente formulario:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST" name="buscar">
        <input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar" placeholder="Buscar:">
        <input type="date" name="fecha1" id="fecha1">
        <input type="date" name="fecha2" id="fecha2">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Buscar">
    </form>
```

Y me manda la siguiente advertencia:

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sana_php\kardex.php on line 37
>   SKU   COSTO   FECHA DE MOVIMIENTO PIEZAS  TICKET  EXISTENCIA FINAL

Podrían ayudarme. GRACIAS

Lo olvidaba, el dato en la base es de tipo DateTime y la manera en que paso por POST es la siguiente:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $buscar=filter_var($_POST['buscar'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $fecha1=$_POST['fecha1'];
        $fecha2=$_POST['fecha2'];
```

En cambio si en el input lo pongo como text en lugar de date , me arroja el siguiente error:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\sana_php\kardex.php on line 41

Comment: Parece correcto, ahora bien, ¿Podrías poner como has declarado tu tabla en sql server y como hacés el post del formulario en php?

Comment: En que formato pasas la fecha?? es con yyyy-mm-dd??

Answer (score 1):

Una opción adicional a la respuesta de Gustavo Piris es agregar la conversion del texto correspondiente a la fecha en el parametro al formato de fecha esperado por la configuracion que tenga el SQL Server.

```
$query="SELECT art_Clave, art_Costo, kar_Fecha, kar_Cantidad, kar_Origen, alma_Existencia FROM tArticuloKardex WHERE art_Clave= ? AND (kar_Fecha BETWEEN convert(varchar(10),?, 103) AND convert(varchar(10),?, 103))";
```

En ese caso suponiendo que quieras asegurar el formato de fecha definido por el codigo 103 según la tabla de [Cast/Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) de SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de la sgte. manera

```
 $query="SELECT art_Clave, art_Costo, kar_Fecha, kar_Cantidad, kar_Origen, alma_Existencia FROM tArticuloKardex WHERE art_Clave= ? AND (kar_Fecha BETWEEN ? AND ?)";

$params = array($buscar, $fecha1, $fecha2); 
$resultado = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);
```